# How to get the output context in dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have created the bot and it contains two intents, each intent is having 20 follow up intents, after completion of one intent it automatically calls the follow-up intent. So the problem is if the user has answered 10 prompts i.e up to 10 follow-up intents and after sometime, the user wants to continue from 11th follow-up intent. Is there any possibility to do that. Currently, I am saving the data of the user previous conversation and trying to start from that conversation point, but after starting the conversation it automatically ask the 11th followup intent prompts and then again it goes to the default-welcome intent instead of continuing with the 12th follow-up intent.

Comment: what is the lifespan of all context ?

Comment: Lifespan depends upon the value you set. Lifespan is still active but then I am unable to continue the conversation at that point where the user has stopped.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the `lifeSpan` that we set in the context, there is also a time-limit for the contexts. After **10 minutes** all the contexts expires so it might be the problem in your case.
In the documentation, it is given that time-out is 20 minutes, but after a lot of testing, it was observed that time-out is indeed 10 minutes.

What you can do is store the context in the some cache or DB after each call, and before calling Dialogflow, append the context with your query from the cache/DB.
I have done the same thing and it is working flawlessly.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @sid8491- What do you mean "before calling Dialogflow, append the context with your query"?

Comment: @SravyaGajavalli if you have given input-context to some intent, that intent will only trigger if that context is present in the query. in your case, the context is being expired due to more than 10 mins activity, so you can send the context along with the text query, so that intent can be triggered. in this way, you will send query request to dialogflow using some SDK.

Comment: @sid8491- so what you are saying is we can handle the session expiry by appending the context(which is stored in the database) along with the text query.

Comment: @sid8491-But in my case the session is not getting expired, the output context is not getting cleared because my conversation is less than 7 min so there is no chance of getting expired.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you did this but I would recommend setting the lifespan of each output context to 1. You might also want to programmatically modify the outpu context if you're using the fulfillment funcitonality. You said you're already keeping track of the previous conversation so I'm assuming that setting it programmatically would be a viable solution for you.